# read file with Phpass with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, phpass

I get this error while using Phpass 0.3 on my CI Controller

Message:

```
is_readable() [function.is-readable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/dev/urandom) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp)
```

Filename: `phpass-0.3/PasswordHash.php`

Can someone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8678566

Answer (score 0):

open_basedir is a directive defined in your php.ini file.

It is set to the lowest directory that you are allowed to access from a PHP script, usually your webroot.

Trying to access a file/directory further down the tree such as in /dev/ will then be dissallowed and you will get the message you have.

You will have to edit your php.ini and set open_basedir to your server root, which is generally a bad thing security-wise as if anyone managed to inject malicious code into your script they would have access to the entire system.

It would be safer to exececute a script (Perl, Python, etc) that lives in your web folder to read /dev/urandom if you really need to.

```
$output = `/scripts/get_urandom.pl`;
// Process output
```

Version 1.8 of phpass [resolves this issue](http://cvsweb.openwall.com/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/projects/phpass/PasswordHash.php) by suppressing the error:

> Changes since revision 1.7: +2 -2 lines:
>
> Prefixed is_readable() with "@" to suppress warning when open_basedir
>   restriction is in effect.